# Spark runs only one executor for large jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a four node hadoop cluster(mapr) with 40GB memory each. My spark startup parameters are as follows:

```
MASTER="yarn-client" /opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin/pyspark --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 5 --driver-memory 20g --driver-cores 10 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize="0" --conf spark.default.parallelism="100"
```

Now when I run my spark job with 100K records, and run results.count() or result.saveTable(), it runs on all the 8 executors. But if I run the job with 1M records, the jobs is split into 3 stages and final stage runs on only ONE executor. Is it something do with partitioning?

Comment: is the final stage a count, or a saveTable, or something else?

Comment: Count in the case of result.count(), SaveTable in the case of result.SaveTable()

Comment: Looks like a data Skew problem, are you using any key/value pairs ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by converting my dataframe into an rdd and repartition it to a large value like greater than 500, instead of using df.withColumn()

pseudo code:

```
df_rdd = df.rdd
df_rdd_partioned = df_rdd.repartition(1000)
df_rdd_partioned.cache().count()
result = df_rdd_partioned.map(lambda r: (r, transform(r)), preservesPartitioning=True).toDF()
result.cache()
```

Comment: what is transform in this case?